# Symfony 1.4 backend two forms in one

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4, yaml, backend

In my backend I have a form for create customers, but I need assign little descriptions to this customers.

Now I have two forms one where I create and modify the info about the customers, and another that I can add or modify the descriptions rows assigned to this customers.
I desire if is possible, create and modify the data of the customers and the data of the descriptions about customers.

I know how to create forms and modify the default values but I don't know how integrate two forms of a model with a relationship of one-to-many.

My schema:

```yml
InfoClient:
  tableName: info_client
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true 
    info_client_type_id:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: true
    name_info_client: 
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
      unique: true

  relations:
    InfoClientLine:
      type: many
      local: id
      foreign: info_client_id

InfoClientLine:
  tableName: info_client_line
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true 
    info_client_id:
      type: integer(4)
    texto:
      type: string()
    info_client_line_type_id:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: true
```

I use the default config file created for symfony.
And the default Model create for symfony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [a great example in the official documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms) about a case: Many photo for a product with this kind of form:

[image]

For you:

- `Product` -> `InfoClient`
- `Photo` -> `InfoClientLine`

Comment: @jOK thank you very much, I did't know the existence of these exemple chapter.